# Have excel carry over the hour in a time column to a second column

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this is a simple question but I cant find a specific answer anywhere. Tried CONCATENATE but that didnt work.

I have a list of excel rows which are all times in the format HH:MM:SS
For example A1 = 20:33:15

I have 10's of thousands of entries and would simply like an excel command that copies the HH to the second B column.

How would I do this?

Comment: That works for a single row but how would I make that recursive throughout the entire A column?

Comment: Worked perfect! want to add it as the answer so I can give you some credit?

Answer (score 0):

get the last row by

> Dim ws As Worksheet
>   
> Dim lastRow As Integer
>   
> lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

and then loop on the particular `Range` and enter `=Hour(Range(<row><col>))`